# Extracting result from integration (quadrature)?

Tags: python

Consider this Python snippet:

```
>>> V=quad(lambda x:sin(x),0,.456)

>>> print "V=",V; 3*V<br>

V= (0.10217888319247767, 1.1344134875077312e-15)
(0.10217888319247767, 1.1344134875077312e-15,
0.10217888319247767, 1.1344134875077312e-15,   
 0.10217888319247767, 1.1344134875077312e-15)<br>>>>
```

How do I get V to just equal 0.10217888319247767, so that
(e.g.) 3*V=.30653664957743301 (i.e., “de-tuple” it)?

Answer (score 0):

You can index the tuple like this: `3*V[0]`

Comment: Please be more elaborated or write it as comment

Comment: Ah, okay, then the proper way to define it is:   “V=quad(lambda x:sin(x),0,.456)”

Comment: Er, make that “V=quad(lambda x:sin(x),0,.456)[0]”.  P=)

Comment: The answer does what the OP wants.